# How to fix "Unity transform position changes after build to WebGL"?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, webgl, unity-webgl

This is my first time to make a Unity project. Everything works well on the Game view in Unity Editor. However, after I built the project and played it on Google Chrome, I found that the position of some gameobjects had been changed.
Here is a more detailed explanation. The left is what I saw on the game view, which was perfect. The right side is what I saw after built the project. The position of the grey picture had been changed.
[image: picture]

Does anyone know how to fix this?

ps.I am using Unity 2020.3.18 with WebGL platform

Comment: Search for how to build your UI for different screen sizes ;)

Comment: Make sure you have the same resolutions set up everywhere - build settings, game preview and if you upload project to itch.io or something similar go carefully about its settings as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try exporting again but with the same resolution as the game view. In this case you would want to export in a 400x600 resolution (You can also edit the "index.html" file to change and experiment with the resolution). The problem has to do with the fact that changing the resolution of the game can affect where certain objects are and how much you can see.